# How to set email and password values from database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET and I want to make a login page where you can insert your mail and password and then log in.

Into `Login.cshtml` I have this markup:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" type="email" value="super@admin.com" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
    <input asp-for="Password" type="password" value="123456" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

In the value fields I had to insert two static values because otherwise I can't login into my web app. How can I accept values from my DB? I have a table `Users` created in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE "Users" 
(
    "Id" NVARCHAR(450) NOT NULL COLLATE 'Latin1_General_CI_AS',
    "AccessFailedCount" INT NOT NULL,
    "ApplicationUserRole" BIT NOT NULL,
    "Email" NVARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'Latin1_General_CI_AS',
    "EmailConfirmed" BIT NOT NULL,
    "PasswordHash" NVARCHAR(max) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'Latin1_General_CI_AS',
    "PhoneNumber" NVARCHAR(max) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'Latin1_General_CI_AS',
    "PhoneNumberConfirmed" BIT NOT NULL,
    "isSuperAdmin" BIT NOT NULL,
    "profilePictureUrl" NVARCHAR(max) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'Latin1_General_CI_AS',
    PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

Comment: Is the question you said very general? Do you use EF?

Comment: @MehranGharzi yes, I use it

Answer (score 0):

I did it for a smaller example

```
public class User 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult NewUser(User model)
{
    using (var db = new IdentityModel())
    {
        db.Plans.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and view

```
@model MyProject.User
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewUser", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(q => q.User)
        @Html.EditorFor(q => q.User, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(q => q.Password)
        @Html.EditorFor(q => q.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
}
```